# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for with belongs_to. How to delete relation, not item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I use Rails 5.1.6 and have troubles with accepts_nested_attributes_for.

I have two models

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rubric, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rubric, allow_destroy: true
end

class Rubric < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :materials, dependent: :nullify
end
```

I don't know how to destroy relation between material and rubric.

I have a test case:

```
it 'should delete relation to rubric' do
  # create two materials with relation to the same rubric
  item = FactoryBot.create(:material_with_rubric)
  expect(Rubric.count).to eq(1)
  expect(item.rubric_id).to_not eq(nil)
  FactoryBot.create(:material, rubric_id: item.rubric_id)
  expect(Material.count).to eq(2)

  # try to destroy relation for first material
  item.assign_attributes(
    rubric_attributes: {
      id: item.rubric_id,
      _destroy: '1'
    }
  )

  # check
  expect(item.valid?).to eq(true)
  expect(item.save).to eq(true)
  expect(item.rubric_id).to eq(nil)
  # rubric should exist in database because we have second material with relation
  expect(Rubric.count).to be > 0
end
```

But, after running test case I see an error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(Rubric.count).to be > 0

   expected: > 0
        got:   0
```

How to destroy a relation using rubric_attributes and don't delete the item from database.
For example accepts_nested_attributes_for with allow_destroy works pretty well with has_many

P.S. I know about item.update(rubric_id: nil). But I want to have the same result using item.update(rubric_attributes: {})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails `nested_attributes` (in particular for this case your `rubic_attributes` Hash) means that you are modifying the associated record(s) and not the record itself. Because `item_id` is an attribute of the Material model and not the associated `Rubic` model, then nested attribute Hash won't be able to update that value (unless its associated record is destroyed through `_destroy`, of which Rails seem to automatically update `material.rubric_id` to `nil`).

But because you do not want to destroy the associated record but just update `material.rubric_id` to `nil` through the `material.update(rubric_attributes: {...})` Hash and that you do not want to use the "normal-way" of simply doing `material.update(rubric_id: nil)`, then you can do a workaround like below which still makes use of `rubric_attributes`:

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :rubric, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rubric, allow_destroy: true
end

class Rubric < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :materials, dependent: :nullify
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :materials
end
```

### Usage:

```
rubric = Rubric.create!
material = Material.create!(rubric: rubric)

material.update!(
  rubric_attributes: {
    id: material.rubric.id,
    materials_attributes: {
      id: material.id,
      rubric_id: nil # or `rubric: nil`
    }
  }
)

puts material.rubric_id
# => 1

# not sure why `material` needs to be reloaded. Rails `inverse_of` seems to not work on "nested" nested_attributes
material.reload

puts material.rubric_id
# => nil

puts Rubric.exists?(id: 1)
# => true

# now you've updated material.rubric_id to nil, but not destroying the Rubric record
```

*IMPORTANT! If this nested attributes is going to be used in the controller, for security purposes, don't forget to only permit the `params.permit(rubric_attributes: [materials_attributes: [:rubric_id]])` ... or any other fields you deem whitelistable.*